# What is the ideal way to use xml data in python html parsing with Beautiful Soup?

Tags: python, html, xml, parsing, beautifulsoup

What is the ideal way to convert xml to text in python html parsing with Beautiful Soup?

When I am doing html parsing with Python 2.7 BeautifulSoup library, I can get to the step to "soup", but I have no idea how to extract the data I need, so I tried converting them all to string.

In the following example, I want to extract all number in the span tag and add them up. Is there a better way?

**XML data:**
http://python-data.dr-chuck.net/comments_324255.html

**CODE:**

```
import urllib2
from BeautifulSoup import *
import re

url = 'http://python-data.dr-chuck.net/comments_324255.html'
html = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
spans = soup('span')
lis = list()
span_str = str(spans)
sp = re.findall('([0-9]+)', span_str)
count = 0
for i in sp:
    count = count + int(i)
print('Sum:', count)
```

Comment: better read BeautifulSoup doc - it has many usefull functions.

Answer (score 1):

Don't need regex:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from requests import get

url = 'http://python-data.dr-chuck.net/comments_324255.html'
html = get(url).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')

count = sum(int(n.text) for n in soup.findAll('span'))
```

Comment: Thanks. This looks way simpler than my code. BTW, what happened in line 4:
    html = get(url).text
and line 8: int(n.text)
Is '.text' an internal method?

Comment: By `.text` you get plane text. It is not a method but a variables in Request and BeautifulSoup objects. They just happen to look the same.

Answer (score 0):

```
import requests, bs4
r = requests.get("http://python-data.dr-chuck.net/comments_324255.html")
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')

sum(int(span.text) for span in soup.find_all(class_="comments"))
```

output:

```
2788
```

Comment: Also thanks to you. Well, beginner has one more question, why is the underscore in     (class_="comments") ? Is it a variable or just convention?